# Show popup when user is not authenticated Django

Tags: django, authentication, django-allauth

I'm using django allauth. But I want to implement django allauth inside a popup instead of a new login page.

Here is the code:

```
contact_entry_form = ContactEntryForm()
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            if request.method == "POST":
                contact_entry_form = ContactEntryForm(request.POST)
                if contact_entry_form.is_valid():
                    ContactEntry.objects.create(
                        name = contact_entry_form.cleaned_data["name"],
                        email = contact_entry_form.cleaned_data["email"],
                        subject = contact_entry_form.cleaned_data["subject"],
                        message = contact_entry_form.cleaned_data["message"])
                    return redirect("mainpage")
        else:
            # I want to change this, showing a popup error on the same page instead of redirecting the user
            return redirect("account_login")
```

The question is: How to return a popup to the current page instead of redirecting the user when the user is not logged in yet?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Django's messages for this.

### views.py

```
from django.contrib import messages

...
# in function
messages.error(request, "User is not authenticated") #or whatever you want
```

or, even better would be to use the message in a function if you want to use the same thing repeatedly

```
def someFunction(message):
    messages.error(request, message) 
    #give message to function from else clause in other function 
    return redirect('login')
    #or, if you want the user to stay on the same page:
    return redirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])
```

### htmlpage.html

(with styling in case you use Bootstrap)

```
<div class="form-group">
    {% for message in messages %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            {{message}}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

#### Django messages

More info on Django message's (specifically message types
can be found here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/messages/#message-levels